# javascript in phonegap for single page application

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I try to convert my web application into Android application, using Phonegap.

The application is very simple: html, javascript, css. Logically it is a single page, which content is changed by a simple javascript code (no any external libraries).

The problem is that, javascript works only for items present on the original page. If an item appeared as a result of a javascript function and has another javascript function assigned to it, that another function never be executed.

What could be the reason? And how can I improve the situation?

**Update:**

the problem is that in case one see the app in a desktop browser window form1 property of the document is defined (it appears on step3), for a mobile app it is not so.
Demo:

```
<html>
<head>
<script  type="text/javascript">


document.onclick = function( whichOne ){ 
    whichOne = whichOne ? whichOne : window.event;
    thisButton = whichOne.target ? whichOne.target : whichOne.srcElement;
    if (thisButton.name) {
        if (thisButton.value == 'Submit') { 
            if (undefined != document.form1){
                alert("yes form1");
            }
            else {
                alert("no form1");
            }
        }
        else if (thisButton.name == 'b1') { 
            var iner ='<center>step 2</center>';
            un1(thisButton.title,iner);
            var oid=thisButton.title;
            iner = t4a(oid,thisButton.name);
            setTimeout( function() { un1(oid,iner);},1000);
        }
    }
}

function un1(id,iner){
    var ele = document.getElementById(id);
    ele.innerHTML = iner;
}

function t4a (id,ara){
    var i; 
    var out="<form name='form1'><center>step 3<table border='1'>"; 
    for (i=0;i < 2;i++){
        out +="<tr><td align='left'>"+i+".</td><td align='right'><input type='text'  name='f"+i+"'></td></tr>";
    }
    out+="</table><input type='button' name='a"+ara+"' title='"+id+"' value='Submit'
></center></form>";
    return out;
}

</script>
</head>

<body>
<center>        
<form >
<div id ="b1">
<input type="button" name="b1" title="b1" value="Butt">
</div>
</form>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi! Could you provide some code?

Comment: I don't know what code do you mean. Android wrapper is pretty much standard (strictly following the instructions on phonegap web site). phonegap is an external package. My web app works fine in a non-mobile web browser. But something is missing

Comment: I mean you HTML and JS code which are inside your folder `www` where you have a problem.

Comment: Please make sure you added all your js bind functions inside document ready method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form >
<div id ="b1">
<input type="button" name="b1" title="b1" value="Butt">
</div>
</form>
```

and you are adding a form inside div "b1"...so form inside form ????
change it to

```
<div id ="b1">
<form >
<input type="button" name="b1" title="b1" value="Butt">
</form>
</div>
```

and it should work.

Comment: in essence, the original form contains more than 1 div. But you're right, I don't need the second form (which is form1). When I got rid of it, everything started to work smoothly. Thanks or the idea :)